# Upload Video to Instagram made with Windows Movie Maker

Tags: video-conversion, video-codecs, windows-movie-maker

I've made a video using Microsoft's Windows Movie Maker and I've tried saving it as "Recommended for this project", "Android Phone (Medium)" and iPhone. It saves the video as a .mp4 using the H.264 codec. Then I upload the .mp4 to my google photos so I can access it on my phone. I go to the video on my phone, hit share to Instagram and I get a message saying "We could not process this video".

The video is 14s long and it's ratio is 4:3 but I can change that using the Instagram app. I've looked up the proper codec and H.264 is it so is there anything I can try to get Instagram to recognize and process my video?

Movie Maker Version: 2012
Computer OS: Windows 10
Phone OS: Android 5.1.1

Comment: Are you having trouble with other apps or just Instagram?